# Error when installing git-credential-helper on OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, git, credentials

I'm trying to get git & github working with this tutorial offered by github.  https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

I have imac with os x 10.7.5.

Everything goes fine until I'm putting credential helper on to work:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
/usr/local/git/bin/git: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/local/git/bin/git: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
```

I have no idea what to do with this syntax error. I've tried uninstalling git and installing it again. I've also searched for the answer, but haven't found this same error from anyone.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I ended up to avoid this problem by just ignoring credentials. This way git works just fine and I didn't have any problems using github from the terminal.

I leave it still open for someone to find an answer for this exact problem.